# Hide a process in the Windows task manager by using task manager hider

Tags: windows-10, process, visual-studio, task-manager

I watched [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dl-Sqp9_em8&ab_channel=BowenFeng) and there you can see how to hide a process by using the software [task manager hider](https://github.com/thebowenfeng/task-manager-hider):

[image]

I tried to use it; in particular I opened the project in Visual Studio 2022, then I right clicked on the folder project, and I compiled it (the compiler did it without any error).

Now I'm wondering how to get the window of the command prompt I showed in the above figure.

Comment: Just run the executable (`.exe`).

Comment: Hello @harrymc in the folder and subfolder there aren't .exe files; maybe it was saved somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The project
[task-manager-hider](https://github.com/thebowenfeng/task-manager-hider)
only creates a DLL.
You will find it inside the `x64` sub-folder of the main folder where
is found the solution file `TaskManagerHack.sln`.

As the description of the project says, the following is up to you:

> Inject the DLL using any method (e.g LoadLibrary) into (64 bit) Task Manager.

The sources for the task that injects the compiled DLL into the
Task Manager are unfortunately not included in this project.

Comment: as usual your answers/comments are very useful! Concerning the injection of the DLL file; do you mean that it should be injected into a process? If yes, maybe this tutorial could be ok? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBwoVUR1gt8&ab_channel=Zer0Mem0ry

Comment: Yes, that's an example of a DLL-injecting process. You will need to modify it so it attacks the Task Manager.